# How to access a second router from a first router using PHP SSH

Tags: php, ssh, remote-access

I want a access a router R2 and run some commands and get the output. Router R2 can not be directly accessed from my PC. To access router R2, I need to first access Router R1 which is directly connected to my PC and then access R2 using ssh command.

Router R1 can be accessed using ssh. Telnet is not allowed in any of the routers. I have found the code to access to access R1 using PHP SSH and it is working fine.

```
    <?php
    $connection = ssh2_connect('IP of R1', 22);
    ssh2_auth_password($connection, 'username', 'password');
    $stream = ssh2_exec($connection, 'command');
    stream_set_blocking($stream, true);
    $output = stream_get_contents($stream);
    echo "<pre>{$output}</pre>";
    ?>
```

Using the above code I can run all the commands and get the output from router R1. But I can not run commands to access router R2. To access R2 from I need to run following commands from R1.

```
<#ssh <IP of R2> //then wait for username prompt
enter username //wait for password prompt
enter password //thats it.
```

Kindly suggest a solution so that I can access R2 via R1 and automate some tasks.

Comment: can u access it from command prompt/terminal?

Answer (score 0):

- Setup ssh key authentification and exchange the puplic keys to each other via ssh tools or adding the keys manually (dont forget to set R1 puplic key also to R1 authorized_keys onto itself)

> ssh-copy-id

- reverse a port on R1 onto another port

> ssh -N -R 1235:localhost:1234  R1_IP # Reverse Tunnel on R1 to listen on 1245 for the outside and reverse it to localhost:1234

- setup forward rule on R1 to forward incoming to local reversed port

> ssh -N -L 1234:R2_IP:22 R1_IP # forward R1:1234 to R2:22

Now connecting from PC to R1:1235 you will end up on R2:22

/etc/ssh/sshd_config on R1 might need to following options set

> GatewayPorts yes